what is a "flag" in bash? and how is it different then other options? what would be a good example to highlight the difference?
so i keep hearing that a flag is a TYPE of option, and that the only difference between a flag and normal options is that a flag is a type of "boolean" option, which when explained to me seems no different then binary
so what is a flag? how is it different then other options?
what would be a good example to show someone in the terminal the difference between flags and other types of options?
thank you

I think you're over-thinking it, but when you use man ls for instance, you'll see many OPTIONS listed as single chars (preceded with a dash), -l for example. But there are also OPTIONS that require a value, like --block-size=SIZE . So you can think of -l as a flag/option that turns on long listings, while --block-size=SIZE would not work if you just used --block-size, so it is not a boolean flag. All in My Humble Opinion. Better to spend your time reading man pages and getting a sense of what each command can do, and possibly how to chain it together with other utils via |
